# React/Redux - View treating array in store as object

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

I have an array at the root level of my Redux store but for some reason my view is treating it as an object.

Code Snippet:

```
const notes = useSelector(state => state.notes)
...
            <p>Notes</p>
            <p>{typeof notes}</p>
            <p>{JSON.stringify(notes)}</p>
            <p>{JSON.stringify(notes[0])}</p>
```

Is showing up as:
[image]

I just want to make sure I'm not crazy and looking at the [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/basic-reducer-structure/#basic-state-shape) it looks like this should be acceptable. Why might this not be working?

### Edit

I'm glad I am not crazy, I guess my follow up question is why do I not see anything when I try:

```
export default function NotesTab() {
    const notes = useSelector(state => state.notes)
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col w-full h-full justify-center items-center">
            {notes.forEach(note => (
                <p>Test</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: That _is_ an array!  (See the square brackets surrounding it?)  Try adding `<p>notes[0].content</p>`.  As for the `typeof`, , in JavaScript arrays aren't actually a type, they are a class so an instance of an array is an object.

Comment: `why do I not see anything`. Maybe try `Array#map` instead of `Array#forEach`. Example:

`{notes.map(note => (<p>Test</p>)}`. Render something if there are no notes, so you can distinguish between your own error and an empty application state. `{(!notes || !notes.length) && (<p>No Notes here</p>)}`

Comment: I think React expects you to use `#map` which will _return_ an array of JSX expressions instead of iterating over your notes with `#forEach`

Comment: That was it, changing it to map fixed it, if you could update your answer to include that I will gladly accept it. :D

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behavior from `typeof` operator. It will report an array as an object. You can use `Array.isArray()` or `Object.prototype.toString.call([])` which will give you `[object Array]`. Or `Object.constructor.name`.

```
> const foo = [1,2];
typeof foo; // object
< "object"

> Object.prototype.toString.call(foo)
< "[object Array]"

> foo.constructor.name
< "Array"
```

You can see from the output of `JSON.stringify(notes)` that your redux selector query is returning an array as you expected, so you should be good. HTH